# Getting firestore usage stats from firebase client libraries

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to identify the reason for an abnormally high firestore read count in my android and web app.

If there was a way to profile firestore, I could get an idea of which collection, or which user is causing this high read count, but currently there is no way to profile firestore.

I added a log entry to my android and web apps to log the read count to a remote server, so I can troubleshoot the issue. But this log doesn't match the actual read count I see in the firestore console, so it looks like I have missed to log some places where firestore is queried.

The reason why firestore hasn't provided a way to profile firestore is because it is technically difficult for them to do it with the high load, as I read somewhere. But, it shouldn't be hard to track the usage at client library level.

Does anyone know a way to get the usage statistics out of the firestore client library? Or any other way to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: This is a common question. Usually, the source of the reads comes from an open console window while data is changing.  There is currently no profiler. Please contact Firebase support and file a feature request to vote for this.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @DougStevenson Read count mismatch is still there even when I don't open the console for days and checked. Also, the duplicate answer you have given doesn't have an answer on whether there is a way to get usage statistics of individual clients from client library itself without contacting the server, which is my actual question.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no profiler. Please [contact Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) and file a feature request to vote for this.  Also, they might be able to help you understand the traffic.